# Iterate over pixels of an image with emgu cv

Tags: c#, image, loops

I want to iterate over all pixel of an image and compare with a search pattern. With best performance possible and in C#. I found emgu cv, a wrapper for Intels opencv. But I don't know how to use emgu properly. Does anybody know how I can do this? What is the data Property of Image? Is this the imagedata? If yes, which value is what? Thanks

#### Update:

I coded my function in C# and it worked well, but way too slow! I had already an algorhytm in c which I translated into C#. C# is 3 to 4 TIMES slower than c! (My function iterates over almost every pixel of an image to seek a shape in an image. -> Hugh Transformation)

Well, I heard that unsafe code could be faster because it does not check array boundries and stuff. Is that true? Runs unsafe code directly on the physically machine?

Anyway, I tried to put unsafe code into my function. But I was not able to get a pointer to my 3D-array or to access the 3D-array with the pointer. How can I rewrite this code from above with unsafe code? And would this bring an additional performance boost or even run as fast as c-code?

Answer (score 58):

As emgu website state there are primarly two strategies:

**The safe (slow) way**

Suppose you are working on an `Image<Bgr, Byte>`.
You can obtain the pixel on the y-th row and x-th column by calling

```
Bgr color = img[y, x];
```

Setting the pixel on the y-th row and x-th column is also simple

```
img[y,x] = color;
```

**The fast way**

The Image pixels values are stored in the Data property, a 3D array. 
Ok so this is true but does not tell how to do it in a real scenario. So let's see some working code and then discuss performance and optimization:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> original = newImage<Bgr, byte>(1024, 768);
Stopwatch evaluator = newStopwatch(); 

int repetitions = 20;
Bgr color = newBgr(100, 40, 243);

evaluator.Start();

for (int run = 0; run < repetitions; run++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < original.Cols; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < original.Rows; i++)
        {
            original[i, j] = color;
        }
    }
}

evaluator.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Average execution time for {0} iteration \n using column per row access: {1}ms\n", repetitions, evaluator.ElapsedMilliseconds / repetitions);
```

So this is the average running time that you have after 20 runs using the safe slow way of setting image pixel
On my machine it takes **1021ms**...

So 1021 milliseconds as average time for looping and setting a number of pixels equal to 1024*768. We could have done a little bit better by looping on row by row

So let's refactor a little bit our code and let's use the faster way using directly Image.Data property:

```
evaluator.Reset();
evaluator.Start();

for (int run = 0; run < repetitions; run++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < original.Rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < original.Cols; j++)
        {
            original.Data[i, j, 0] = 100;
            original.Data[i, j, 1] = 40;
            original.Data[i, j, 2] = 243;
        }
    }
}

evaluator.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Average execution time for {0} iterations \n using Data property: {1}ms\n", repetitions, evaluator.ElapsedMilliseconds / repetitions);
```

On my machine it takes **519ms**.
So we have gained a performance boost of 50%. The execution time has been decreased by a factor of two.

So looking carefully at the code keeping in mind that we are using C#, we can do a minor change that will drastically boost again our image pixel setting performance... **we should not use c# property inside a loop!!!**

```
evaluator.Reset();
evaluator.Start();

byte[,,] data = original.Data;

for (int run = repetitions - 1; run >= 0; run--)
{
    for (int i = original.Rows - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = original.Cols - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            data[i, j, 0] = 100;
            data[i, j, 1] = 40;
            data[i, j, 2] = 243;
        }
    }
}

evaluator.Stop();
```

With this latest piece of code you will have a huge performance boost **(73ms)** due to correct use of C# language.

Comment: Thank you so much for that detailed answer! I didn't know that rule, not to use Properties in a loop. 

One additional question: What does that mean: "unsafe data property". Unsafe in what manner? What are the risks?

Comment: There's nothing unsafe in using data property. The developer need more attention in specifying the correct index to get or set the correct value because Data property it's a 3 dimensional array

Comment: I would appreciate if you could share how long time it takes in the last one (not using property)

Comment: @Ali Veli: I edit the answer and add how long does it take for the last example

Comment: Why there is this abrupt decrease in time? It's looks like the compiler needs some optimization here. Is this C# 5?

Comment: @Pedro77 Even if `Data` doesn't do any kind of validation or comprehensive branching (which it probably doesn't), unless the underlying value is marked `readonly`, the compiler will have no reasonably easy way of knowing if another thread might have changed what it refers to.

Comment: Also this still isn't using `unsafe`, and so you're still incurring the cost of bounds checking.

Comment: i am surprised when i tested the 3rd method with this loop and time increases 10 times, why ?
 for (int run = 0; run < repetitions; run++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < original.Rows; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < original.Cols; j++)
                    {
                        zz++;
                        data[i, j, 0] = 0;

                        data[i, j, 1] = 0;
                        data[i, j, 2] = 255;
                    }
                }
            }

Comment: Ok i got it

instead of matching i<origioanl.rows, i saved origional.rows and .cols  in int variable and then processed, time reduced 10 times. Its excellent

Comment: Why did you flip the range? i.e. in the first snippet you iterated from [0 to rows] and then you iterate from [row to 0]

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to supplement the already thorough answer of @Luce Del Tongo and @Dent7777 with one further solution for per-value operations on image data using emgucv. Whilst my testing (same method) shows only equivalent performance to that of the final solution above; I believe that it's a valuable alternative.

The Image.Convert() method has a number of powerful overloads that can be used to apply delegate Functions per-value on the calling image to return a resulting image of the same or differing TDepth. See **"Generic Operation"** at http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images for more detail.

Most significant is the ability to pass up to three additional images as parameters to the Convert method, the contained data of which will be passed to the delegate.

For example, a complex filter:

```
// From the input image "original"
Image<Bgr, Byte> original = new Image<Bgr, byte>(1024, 768);

// I wish to produce an image "result"
Image<Gray, double> result = new Image<Gray, double>(1024, 768);

// Whereby each "result" pixel is
Bgr originalPixel;
double resultPixel =
(0.5 + Math.Log(originalPixel.Green) -
(0.5 * Math.Log(originalPixel.Red)) -
(0.5 * Math.Log(originalPixel.Blue)));
```

To use the solution provided in previous answer:

```
byte[,,] sourceData = original.Data;
double[,,] resultData = result.Data;
for (int i = original.Rows - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for (int j = original.Cols - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        resultData[i,j,0] =
        (0.5 + Math.Log(sourceData[i, j, 1]) -
        (0.5 * Math.Log(sourceData[i, j, 2])) -
        (0.5 * Math.Log(sourceData[i, j, 0])));
    }
}
```

Average Time on my machine: **(676ms)**

**Alternatively**, I can call Convert on the Blue channel of the original, passing the other two channels as parameters, along with a delegate method of corresponding signature to perform my computation:

```
result =
    original[0].Convert<byte, byte, double>(
    original[1],
    original[2],
    Compute);
```

Where:

```
private double Compute(byte B, byte G, byte R)
{
    return (0.5 + Math.Log(G) - (0.5 * Math.Log(R)) - (0.5 * Math.Log(B)));
}
```

Average Time on my machine: **(674ms)**

Perhaps just personal preference, but I hope this may be of value to someone somewhere.