# "Is there any way to access a pixel by in an image by particular position like(x,y) in opencvforunity"

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to access image pixels by position i have been use byte array for accessing but it does not give the correct position of x,y like python image[x][y] is there any better way to access pixels?

i have used opencv plugin in unity,visual studio and cannot access them

```
public texture2D image;

Mat imageMat = new Mat(image.height, image.width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
Utils.texture2DToMat(image, imageMat); // actually converts texture2d to matrix

byte[] imageData = new byte[(int)(imageMat.total() * imageMat.channels())]; // pixel data of image
imageMat.get(0, 0, imageData);// gets pixel data

pixel=imageData[(y * imageMat.cols() + x) * imageMat.channels() + r]
```

y and x are pixel values in the code and r is the channel but i'm not able to
access a particular value of x and y with that code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004480/get-and-set-pixel-gray-scale-image-using-emgu-cv

Answer (score 1):

There is no usual way to do it because operation is really slow. But some trick to do it is you can make screen texture from '[Camera](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.Render.html%0A)' class.

After you make texture, you can use texture.GetPixel(x,y)

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Take a "screenshot" of a camera's Render Texture.
    Texture2D RTImage(Camera camera)
    {
        // The Render Texture in RenderTexture.active is the one
        // that will be read by ReadPixels.
        var currentRT = RenderTexture.active;
        RenderTexture.active = camera.targetTexture;

        // Render the camera's view.
        camera.Render();

        // Make a new texture and read the active Render Texture into it.
        Texture2D image = new Texture2D(camera.targetTexture.width, camera.targetTexture.height);
        image.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, camera.targetTexture.width, camera.targetTexture.height), 0, 0);
        image.Apply();

        // Replace the original active Render Texture.
        RenderTexture.active = currentRT;
        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please let me tell how to access the pixel from specific location so that i can push other image data in to present image at particular positions please let me know if there is a way