# EmguCV Object Detection stack overflow

Tags: c#, algorithm, opencv, recursion, emgucv

I'm trying to walk through all of the pixels in a binary EmguCV image by following the code shown here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5107490/1092688

And make a recursive call on any white pixels found and place the contiguous object into its own binary image. There is a List which stores these binary images, and then I need to perform some operations on the list. However, I'm getting a stack overflow error in my recursive function. The code block which iterates over an image is shown here:

```
    //globals:
    byte[,,] outputData;
    byte[,,] inputData;
    int count = 0;

    //iterative loop
    inputData = input.Data;
    for (int i = input.Rows - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (int j = input.Cols - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if (inputData[i, j, 0] == 255)
                {
                    count = 0;
                    Image<Gray, Byte> temp = new Image<Gray, Byte>(input.Size);
                    outputData = temp.Data;

                    crawlFrom(i, j);
                    //outputData should now contain a byte[,,] representing the data of a single object to be processed.
                }
            }
        }
```

And the recursive function is shown below (note that it uses the globals shown above):

```
private void crawlFrom(int i, int j)
    {
        outputData[i, j, 0] = 255;//add pixel to output
        count++;//increment count
        inputData[i, j, 0] = 0;//blacken input image

        //recursively call on neighbors:
        if(i + 1 < height)
            if (inputData[i + 1, j, 0] == 255)
                crawlFrom(i + 1, j);

        if (i - 1 >= 0)
            if (inputData[i - 1, j, 0] == 255) 
                crawlFrom(i - 1, j);

        if (j + 1 < width)
            if (inputData[i, j + 1, 0] == 255) 
                crawlFrom(i, j + 1);

        if (j - 1 >= 0)
            if (inputData[i, j - 1, 0] == 255) 
                crawlFrom(i, j - 1);

    }
```

I checked the color of the neighbor before recursively calling on it in an attempt to thwart the stack overflow, *yes* I have also tried it with

```
if(inputData[i, j, 0] == 0) return;
```

at the start of the function.

Some other info:
Stack size is 1GB
Image size is 1920x1080
The image should have less than 10% white pixels. It does seem that the images which cause the stack overflow tend to have more white pixels (perhaps up to 30%).
This is a real-time application.
Objects are not always closed shapes.

How can I solve this problem? I'm pretty unfamiliar with how the Image.Data property works and whether or not I'm using it properly so I hope it's something obvious. If it's not a simple bugfix, I'm open to suggestions for tweaking my existing algorithm or changing my algorithm for object detection altogether, so long as the solution fits my criteria for detection and speed.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: As a general tip, never use a recursive solution for an unbounded problem. Use a private stack instead of using the thread stack, thus preventing an unrecoverable stack-overflow exception.

Comment: Is this an unbounded problem? The image's size is known and the end condition is well-defined. Sorry if I'm not looking at it the right way though.

Comment: I say it's "unbounded" because your program could be given a 2-million-by-2-million pixel sized image, which would also cause it to fail. When designing or implementing an algorithm always consider how it handles extreme-sized inputs.

Comment: @Dai luckily the size of the image is hard coded (using an OpenCV ROI) to a bounded size. Thanks for the concern though

Comment: You do realize that you are only looking at single channel of a pixel, specifically the red channel? The second comment I would like to offer is do not use i and j, use a better name like row and column makes the code easier to read. And I agree with Dai, this could be unbounded and there is not any information in your question that would indicate you have a finite size.

Comment: @AeroClassics since it's a binary image, there is no reason to look at more than one channel. Thanks for the formatting tip but I don't understand how you can say this " there is not any information in your question that would indicate you have a finite size" when the questions says this: "Image size is 1920x1080"