# Emug cv C# minimum Threshold truncate

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

Using emug cv 4.4 in C#.

Let's say I have graycale 16 bit images covering whole range. I want to truncate both lower and upper values to predefined min and max and later normalize image so I cover whole possible range.

For trancating to upper value there is an easy solution:

```
CvInvoke.Threshold(imgIn, imgOut, max, 65535, ThresholdType.Trunc);
```

returning:

```
"value = value > threshold ? threshold : value"
```

I want the same method but for min value, so something doing this

```
"value = value < threshold ? threshold : value"
```

So far I couldn't find any elegant solution searching documentation and stackoverflow.

The way I currently implemented it (and it's working) is to make negative of imgIn, applay Threshold method and once agian make negative:

```
CvInvoke.BitwiseNot(imgIn, imgOut);
CvInvoke.Threshold(imgOut, imgOut, 65535-min, 65535, ThresholdType.Trunc);
CvInvoke.BitwiseNot(imgOut, imgOut);
```

I am wondering if there is more elegant solution to this.
Later I convert this image to 8bit and apply colorization.

```
CvInvoke.Normalize(imgOut, imgOut, 0, 255, NormType.MinMax, DepthType.Cv8U);
CvInvoke.ApplyColorMap(imgOut, imgOutColor, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ColorMapType.Jet);
```

So in summary I want to truncate 16bit grayscale input image to both predefined min and max values, normalize it's range to cover whole 8bit image in order colorize it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Congratulations on your first question; perfectly conforming to all best practices :)

Answer (score 0):

I've understood your question to be specifically to the thresholding/truncating and that you are happy with the subsequent normalization.

A little known trick with EmguCV is the ability to use `Image.Convert()` in order to apply "pixel-wise" function delegates to your images. To achieve your need, you may use your own logic:

```cs
Image<Gray, ushort> minThresholded = inputImage.Convert((value) => value = value < lowerThreshold ? lowerThreshold : value);
Image<Gray, ushort> maxThresholded = minThresholded.Convert((value) => value = value > upperThreshold ? upperThreshold : value);
```

You may be interested to read Luca's and my answer here: [Iterate over pixels of an image with emgu cv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101986/iterate-over-pixels-of-an-image-with-emgu-cv/60994504#60994504)